# Migrating a gem to ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-1.9.3

Hello I am trying to use/port a gem written for mri 1.8 in ruby 1.9

This is a sample of the code which I can't port.

```
module ClassMethods
  ...
  private
  ...
  def prepend_interceptors_to_chain(condition, interceptors)
    interceptors = interceptors + read_inheritable_attribute("#{condition}_invocation_interceptors")
    write_inheritable_attribute("#{condition}_invocation_interceptors", interceptors)
  end
  ...
end
```

the match in ruby 1.9 will be something like

```
def prepend_interceptors_to_chain(condition, interceptors)
  interceptors = interceptors + self.:"#{condition}_invocation_interceptors"
  self.:"#{condition}_invocation_interceptors" =  interceptors
end
```

is it possible to use a string as a name to access a class variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `.send(:method)`:

```
def prepend_interceptors_to_chain(condition, interceptors)
  interceptors = interceptors + self.send("#{condition}_invocation_interceptors")
  self.send("#{condition}_invocation_interceptors=", interceptors)
end
```

Comment: I can't use the `send` method to set values.
Do I need some library or something that I am missing?
The `send` is only for invoking methods or I can use it also with varaibles?

Comment: You can use the send method to set values: `@user.send('firstname=', 'Billy')` (notice the equal after the attribute name) @fabio